# Inequalities between means of random variables

Tags: probability

**a.** 
$E(X^2) ... E(X)$
**b.** $E(X^2) ... (EX)^2$
**c.** $E(X^2).. Var X$
**d.** $(EX)^2... Var X$

**a.** It depends, there is no inequality.
Examples:
variable on two points:  $Pr(X=1/2)=Pr(X=-1/2)=1/2 \rightarrow EX = 1/2 * 1/2 + (-1/2) * 1/2 = 0$
$E(X^2)= 1/4 * 1/2 + 1/4 * 1/2 = 1/4 > 0 = EX$
And second example:
$Pr(X=1/2)=1/2. Pr(X=1) = 1/2\to EX = 1/2 * 1/2 + 1/2 * 1 = 3/4$
$EX^2 = 1/2 * (1/4) + 1/2 * 1 = 1/2 + 1/8 = 0.625 < 3/4 = EX$
**b.**
$Var X = E(X^2) - (EX)^2$.
Then, if $E(X^2) \le (EX)^2$ then  we have that always $Var X \le 0$ what is obvious false. Similiary, if $E(X^2) \ge (EX)^2$ the always $Var X \ge 0$  what is also false.
So there is no global relation.

**c.**
$Var X = EX^2- (EX)^2 \le E(X^2) \Leftrightarrow -(EX)^2 \le 0$, hence:  $Var X\le E(X^2)$

**d.**
I am not sure about this point, Can you help me ?
Tell me also please - Am I right when it comes to **a., b., c.** ?

Comment: Why would $\textrm{Var}\geq 0$ be false? How was the variance introduced to you?

Comment: (Also, regarding the vote to close this time: what is "unclear [about what the OP is] asking"? It seems pretty clear.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. and c. seem right.

b. Actually, $Var(X) \ge 0$ always. It may help to consider the equivalent definition of variance $Var(X)=E[(X-E[X])^2]$.

d. If $X$ is a nonzero constant, then $(EX)^2 > 0 = Var(X)$. If $X$ take values $1$ and $-1$ with equal probability then $Var(X) = 1 > 0 = (EX)^2$.

Comment: So, because of always $Var X\ge 0$ we have that $EX^2 \ge (EX)^2$ Yeah ?

Comment: thanka, uncerdibly clear answer!